# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.javac.KaptJavaCompiler?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm getting this strange AccessError after implementing Firebase Database dependencies. I had Firebase Authentication and Firebase Analytics enabled before loading Firebase Database. I'm using it as described in the Firebase documentation, with Firebase BOM.

I really don't understand why there is a failure with my JDK compiler. It seems like all my Gradle versions are up to date.

Project gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        nav_version = "2.5.3"
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
        view_model = "2.4.1"
    }
    
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:2.0.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.4' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.4' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.0' apply false
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.0" apply false
}
```

Module gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") // Firebase
    id 'kotlin-kapt'//Navigation

}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.dine_aid'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dine_aid"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")
            def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
            keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

            buildConfigField "String", "API_TOKEN", keystoreProperties["API_TOKEN"]
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.android.car.ui:car-ui-lib:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-common:2.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.7.10"

    //Firebase
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.6.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database")
    //LocalDate
    implementation "org.threeten:threetenbp:1.5.1"
    //RecyclerView
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.1")
    //ImageLoader Coil
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:2.2.2")
    //Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.14.0"
    //Material
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<version>'
    //Navigation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
    //Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.2'
    // Coil
    implementation "io.coil-kt:coil:2.2.2"
    // HTML parsing Jsoup
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.14.3'
    //Nested ScrollView
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

gradle.properties:

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app's APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Kotlin code style for this project: "official" or "obsolete":
kotlin.code.style=official
# Enables namespacing of each library's R class so that its R class includes only the
# resources declared in the library itself and none from the library's dependencies,
# thereby reducing the size of the R class for that library
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true
android.nonFinalResIds=false
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
#Fri Oct 06 14:30:46 CEST 2023
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

and here is the whole Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.javac.KaptJavaCompiler (in unnamed module @0x52cfe3c1) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.main to unnamed module @0x52cfe3c1
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1027)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:524)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:427)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:421)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:714)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:420)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:593)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.KaptContext.<init>(KaptContext.kt:55)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.KaptContextForStubGeneration.<init>(KaptContextForStubGeneration.kt:38)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.contextForStubGeneration(Kapt3Extension.kt:295)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:174)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:104)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:104)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:114)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:256)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:247)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:87)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:168)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:100)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:460)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.doCompile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:476)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:399)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileNonIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:280)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:124)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:636)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1598)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:714)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:598)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:844)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:720)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

Errors were stored into /Users/az2k4/AndroidStudioProjects/Dine_aid/.gradle/kotlin/errors/errors-1702057165982.log
```

I've tried to fire up Kotlin version 1.9.21 with JDK version 17, but with exactly the same result. I've experimented with a few other combinations, earlier versions, and the latest versions. The error code remains the same, no matter what I change.

I really don't understand why this is happening after I loaded the database dependency from Firebase. Before this, everything worked fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks a lot in advance.

Best regards,
a-bytecode

Comment: For everybody who had the same issue, this problem was solved by updating my IDE to the newest version (Android Studio Hedgehog).